# display notification at add new item in recyclerview even if app is not running

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to display a notification when new item is insert in recyclerview even if app is running or not

i tried:

```
RecyclerAdapter recyclerAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(getActivity(), title, date, content);
recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);

int newCount = recyclerAdapter.getItemCount();
int previousItem = getFromSavePref(); 
if(previousItem < newCount)
{
     updateNotification();
     previousItem=newCount;
     savedInSharedPref(previousItem);
}
```

getFromSavePref() and savedInSharedPref(int value) method avaliable in Session class which is used to manage shared prefrences, recyclerAdapter is adapter class for recyclerView.

```
public void updateNotification(){
        NotificationCompat.Builder notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getActivity());

            notification.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

        notification.setContentTitle(getString(R.string.update));
        notification.setContentText(getString(R.string.notificatiocontent));
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Main.class);
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(getActivity());
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(Main.class);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        notification.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0, newsNotification.build());
    }
```

notification is coming only when app is running, i want to show it even if is not running

and please let me know if i call updateNotification() in right place or it is needed to somewhere else.

Comment: If your app is not running there wont be a recylcerview availalbe which adds your items ;-)

Comment: then what should i do for this

Comment: for that you have to run webservice in some interval in background using Service. and if you get new data then you can push your notification.

Comment: hi @Akash where should i use Service in my code and do i need BroadCastReciever here, and please provide some example if it is possible